# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined "

Tags: javascript

i'm getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

for some reason in this line

```
world_map_array[i][z]="grass.gif|ongrass.gif|collision.gif|above.gif";
```

Why is this happening?

thanks for any help

```
var x_world_map_tiles = 100; 
var y_world_map_tiles = 100; 

var world_map_array = new Array(x_world_map_tiles);
for (i=0; i<=2; i++)//create a two dimensional array so can access the map through x and y coords map_array[0][1] etc.
{
world_map_array[i]=new Array(y_world_map_tiles);
}


for (i=0; i<=x_world_map_tiles; i++)//just a test
{
for (z=0; z<=y_world_map_tiles; z++)//just a test
{
world_map_array[i][z]="grass.gif|ongrass.gif|collision.gif|above.gif";
}
}
```

Comment: *Why is this happening?* Because `world_map_array[i]` is `undefined` at some point. If an array has length, say, `3`, then the indexes are `0`, `1`, `2`. Also, if you never assigned a value to an index, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is create a two dimensional array to represent a tile map. e.g.

`[0,0][1,0][2,0]
[0,1][1,1][2,1]
[0,2][1,1][2,2]`

Comment: I think you would profit from reading the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), especially the section about arrays.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript have quirks of their own that you may not be expecting if you come from other languages. Two important ones for your use case are:

1. You cannot directly declare multidimension arrays in JavaScript.
2. There's little efficiency benefit (and no added safety) when you set the size of the array at creation.

Unlike other languages, JavaScript won't allocate a block of memory for the full array. 
(It doesn't know what kind of objects you're going to be putting in each cell, 
and therefore how much total memory it will need.)
Instead, all the `size` argument to `Array()` does for you is set the array's `length` property.

For the general, 2d array case, I'd suggest:

1. Create the "top" array, e.g.:

   ```
   var i       // the first-order index in a
     , j       // the second order index in a
     , a = []
   ```
2. Initialize array elements as needed. 
   This is called [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), 
   and, in this case, it simply involves testing that `a[i]` exists 
   before we try to assign something to `a[i][j]`, e.g.:

   ```
   if (!a[i]) a[i] = []
   ```

   In English the above statement reads:
   "If the i-th element of `a` is 'falsy', assign an empty array to the i-th element."
3. Finally, assign the actual value to the multideminsional array:

   ```
   a[i][j] = 'whatever'
   ```

For your case, you know the values ahead of time,
so you can initialize each element in advance.
(If you're not overriding most of the elements, however, 
a lazy implementation may be better; see below.)

```
var x, x_length = 100
  , y, y_length = 100
  , map = []

// Don't be lazy
for (x = 0; x < x_length; x++) {
  map[x] = []
  for (y = 0; y < y_length; y++) {
    map[x][y] = 'grass.gif|ongrass.gif|collision.gif|above.gif'
  }
}
```

As some others have said, 
an array with 100 elements has indexes numbered from *zero* to *ninety-nine*, 
so a less-than comparison is most appropriate here.

---

For reference, here's an implementation that uses lazy initialization.
I've gone with a function interface instead of directly accessing the array;
it's longer and more complex, but also more complete.

The initialization pattern I've used here is called an 
[immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).
If you haven't seen it before, 
it's one of the more useful JavaScript patterns 
and well worth taking some time to understand.

```
var map = (function (x_length, y_length, v_default, undefined) {
  // Unless v_default is overwritten, use ...
  v_default = v_default || 'grass.gif|ongrass.gif|collision.gif|above.gif'

  // Private backing array; will contain only values for a[x][y] 
  // that were explicitly set.
  var a = []

  // Private helper function. 
  // - Returns `true` if `x` is between `0` and `x_length - 1`
  //   and `y` is between `0` and `y_length - 1`.
  // - Returns `false` otherwise.
  function valid (x, y) {
    return (x >= 0 
      &&    x <  x_length
      &&    y >= 0
      &&    y <  y_length)
  }

  // Private helper function.
  // - Returns `true` if a[x][y] has been set().
  // - Returns `false` otherwise.
  function exists (x, y) {
    return !!a[x] && !!a[x][y]
  }

  // Private getter
  // - Returns the value of a[x][y] if it has been set().
  // - Returns `undefined` if the point (x,y) is invalid.
  // - Returns `v_default` otherwise.
  function get (x, y) {
    if (!valid(x, y))      return undefined
    else if (exists(x, y)) return a[x][y]
    else                   return v_default
  }

  // Private setter
  // - Returns the value set on success.
  // - Returns `undefined` on failure
  function set (x, y, v) {
    if (valid(x, y)) {
      // We're being lazy
      if (!a[x]) a[x] = []
      a[x][y] = v
      return a[x][y]
    }
    return undefined
  }

  // Return an interface function. 
  // - Pass the function three arguments, (x, y, v), to set a[x][y] = v
  // - Pass the function two arguments, (x, y), to get a[x][y]
  return function (x, y, v) {
    if (arguments.length > 2) {
       return set(x, y, v)
    } else {
       return get(x, y)
    }
  }
})(100, 100)
```

When I ran the above in node, the following tests printed sensible values:

```
// Invalid invocations
console.log('map()                : %s', map())
console.log('map(  0)             : %s', map(0))
console.log('map( -1,   0)        : %s', map(-1,0))
console.log('map(  0,  -1)        : %s', map(0, -1))
console.log('map( -1,  -1)        : %s', map(-1, -1))

// Valid invocations
console.log('map(  0,   0)        : %s', map(0, 0))
console.log('map( 99,  99)        : %s', map(99, 99))
console.log('map(  1,   1)        : %s', map(1,1))
console.log('map(  1,   1, "foo") : %s', map(1,1, 'foo'))
console.log('map(  1,   1)        : %s', map(1,1))
```

Comment: Very thorough answer and you had me realise my problem which is related to the original post's error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
var x_world_map_tiles = 100;
var y_world_map_tiles = 100;
var world_map_array = new Array(x_world_map_tiles);
for (i=0; i<=2; i++)//create a two dimensional array 
{
    world_map_array[i]=new Array(y_world_map_tiles);
}
for (i=0; i<x_world_map_tiles; i++)
{
    for (z=0; z<y_world_map_tiles; z++)
    {
        world_map_array[i][z]="grass.gif|ongrass.gif|collision.gif|above.gif";
    }
}
```

As your array has a length of 100, you must go from `0` to `99` (<100) and not to `100` (<=)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
```

must be:

```
for (i=0; i<=x_world_map_tiles ; i++)
```

Comment: No, it must be `for (i=0; i < x_world_map_tiles ; i++)`.

Comment: @FelixKling See `'for (i=0; i<=x_world_map_tiles; i++)//just a test'` in below.

Comment: Ok, agreed, it would work, but that is actually incorrect as well ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Why is it incorrect?   Because the OP defines 100, but creates 101 instances?

Comment: Yep. And I think this is the actual issue here or at least the OP should be made aware of the fact that one iterates over the array from `0` to `length - 1`.

Comment: @FelixKling C'mon man ! Read the title of question. So my answer resolves that issue, not the 'logical errors'.

Comment: I'm just explaining my point of view, you have a different one, that's fine.

Comment: @FelixKling Did you explain it by `downvoting`?

Comment: No, I explained it with [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673237/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-0-of-undefined/10673268#comment13848015_10673268).

Answer (score 0):

You're feeding the `world_map_array[i]` expression a value for `i` that does not exist in 
`world_map_array`. So I guess `x_world_map_titles` is > 2.

I think you need to rewrite `i<=2` to `i<=x_world_map_titles`

Also you do not need to specify the size of the array. I would just use literals in this case:

```
var x_world_map_tiles = 100;  
var y_world_map_tiles = 100; 

var world_map_array = [];
for (i=0; i<=x_world_map_tiles; i++)
  //create a two dimensional array of 101x101 so can access the map through x and y coords map_array[0][1] etc. { 
  world_map_array[i]=[];
}

for (i=0; i<=x_world_map_tiles; i++)//just a test { 
  for (z=0; z<=y_world_map_tiles; z++)//just a test { 
    world_map_array[i][z]="grass.gif|ongrass.gif|collision.gif|above.gif"; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Getting Uncaught TypeError while using 2-D array in javascript.

For two- dimension array, first declare parent array

var arryTwoDimension= [];

Then depending on the situation, we can create child array by

arryTwoDimension[i]=[]   i will be from 0,1,2......

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Please let us know which language you're using, and use the backtick ` around code snippets to make it easier to parse your question.