# Dynamic Google Apps Script Array Construction failure

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dynamic-arrays, dynamically-generated

Essentially I am looking through a previously created two dimensional array and wanting to output every value that matches a specific case in another two dimensional array.

```
function FruitsToEat() {
  var fruits = [
    ["Name",      "TastesGood?", "ShouldEat?"],
    ["Apple",     true,          true],
    ["Orange",    false,         true],
    ["Grapes',    true,          true],
    ["Forbidden", true,          false]
  ];
  var EatThese = [];
  var i = 0;
  var rows = 0;
  var columns = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {        //Check the entire Array
    if (fruits[i][2] == true) {                //If the "ShouldEat?" column = true
      if (column != 2) {                       //Once column reaches 2, make a new row
        EatThese[row][column] = fruits[i][0];  //Set the cell to the fruit name
        column++;                              //Move to the right in the array
      } else {
        row++;                                 //Move down one in the array
        column = 0;                            //Move back to the left of the array
        EatThese[row][column] = fruits[i][0];  //Set the cell to the fruit name
        column++;                              //Move to the right in the array
      }
    }
  }

  return EatThese;
}
```

The output is always:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property "0.0" of undefined to "Apple". (line 16, file "StackOverflow.com")
```

When I expect it to be

```
Apple Orange
Grapes
```

In their respective cells in Sheets.

**So I solved it myself while typing this up. I'll leave this here because I couldn't find help anywhere**

I would still like to know why my initial idea did not work if somebody can tell me.

```
function FruitsToEat() {
  var fruits = [
    ["Name",      "TastesGood?", "ShouldEat?"],
    ["Apple",     true,          true],
    ["Orange",    false,         true],
    ["Grapes',    true,          true],
    ["Forbidden", true,          false]
  ];
  var EatThese = [];                          //This is our main array and will be what we return.
  var EatTheseTemp = [];                      //This is our temporary array. It will store each row of the main array until it is filled.
  var i = 0;
  var rows = 0;
  var columns = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {        //Check the entire Array
    if (fruits[i][2] == true) {                //If the "ShouldEat?" column = true
      if (column != 2) {                       //Our fill detection
        EatTheseTemp[column] = fruits[i][0];   //Set the cell to the fruit name
        column++;                              //Move to the right in the temporary array
      } else {
        EatThese[row] = EatTheseTemp;          //Start constructing the main array
        row++;                                 //Prepare for the next fill
        column = 0;                            //Move back to the left of the temporary array
        EatTheseTemp = [];                     //Reset our temporary array
        EatTheseTemp[column] = fruits[i][0];   //Set the cell to the fruit name
        column++;                              //Move to the right in the temporary array
      }
    }
  }

  EatThese[row] = EatTheseTemp;

  return EatThese;
}
```

Essentially I made two arrays. One array has pieces added to it each time the initial if statement returns true. Once the embedded if statement shows that this array has filled up, the complete row is added to the main array and then the other variables are wiped to start over. Outside of the for loop you need to add the final row and the two dimensional array is complete.

Comment: Your initial code didn't work because you were trying to assign a value to `eatThese[0][0]`. You'd defined `eatThese` as an Array, but that does not define the elements of the array... `eatThese[0]` will be `undefined` until you assign something to it. In this case, make it an array... `eatThese[0] = [];`, then you can go ahead and assign `eatThese[0][0]`. There is [lots of help on this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+two+dimensional+array).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673237/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-0-of-undefined)