# Javascript loop error: Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am practicing Javascript and have the following code which returns an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` error on the `sets[i][j] = initial_sets [i][j];` line. The idea seems to be correct, but I can't figure out why I am getting the error.

```
var sets = [[],[]]; //Declared this 2D array based on solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512182/how-to-create-empty-2d-array-in-javascript
var initial_sets=[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]; //2D array
var i,j;

//2D array sets is being filled by 2D array initial_sets
for (i=0; i<initial_sets.length; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<initial_sets[i].length; j++) {
            sets[i][j] = initial_sets[i][j];
    }
}
```

I tried the solution posted in [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673237/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-0-of-undefined) by creating a 1D array and then assigning another dimension to it, but I still get the same error.

Comment: You have 3 arrays in `initial_sets` but only 2 in `sets` so `set[2]` is `undefined`

Comment: `initial_sets` is a 2D array though

Comment: What is the end goal of the code?

Comment: [[],[]]; here size of array is 2, so how can you fit anything at 3rd index

Comment: based on this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512182/how-to-create-empty-2d-array-in-javascript it is a declaration for a 2D array. not an array with only 2 indices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sets = [];
var initial_sets=[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]];
var i,j;

for (i=0; i<initial_sets.length; i++) {
    // check if sets[i] exist. if not push a new emty array to it.
    if(!sets[i]) sets.push([]);
    for (j=0; j<initial_sets[i].length; j++) {
            sets[i][j] = initial_sets[i][j];
    }
}
```

then you won't have to initialize `sets` with empty arrays, it will push them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions of the arrays are not the same.

```
var sets = []; 
var initial_sets=[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]];
var i,j;

for (i=0; i<initial_sets.length; i++) { 
    var tmp = [];
    for (j=0; j<initial_sets[i].length; j++) {
            tmp[j] = initial_sets[i][j];
    }
    sets[i] = tmp;
}
```

OR

```
var sets = []; 
var initial_sets=[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]];
var i,j;

for (i=0; i<initial_sets.length; i++) { 
    sets[i] = []; 
    for (j=0; j<initial_sets[i].length; j++) {
            sets[i][j] = initial_sets[i][j];
    }    
}
```

Comment: yes, they are.. they are both 2D. And `sets` will dynamically increase to the size of `initial_sets`.

Comment: @user2883071 When `i==2`, `sets[i]` is undefined. It's true dynamically increases but the value of `sets[2]` is `undefined`. So `sets[2][j]` is `undefined` and can not be set

Comment: Apologies, I see what you are saying. I believe my confusion arose when I tried to declare a 2D array. I tried initializing a 2D array as such: `var sets = [][];` but that gave me an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`, which is why I used `var sets = [[],[]];`

Comment: It was based on the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512182/how-to-create-empty-2d-array-in-javascript

Comment: @user2883071 You defined `[[], []]` correctly. And you know access array with indices causes the array length to be increased. But the point is when you want to access to `sets[i][j]` and `i==2`, the `sets[i]` does not get valued yet and is `undefined`. So before accessing to `sets[2][j]` you need to set value for `sets[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var sets = [];
var initial_sets=[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']];
var i,j;

for (i=0; i<initial_sets.length; i++){ 
  sets[i]=[];
  for (j=0; j<initial_sets[i].length; j++){
    sets[i].push(initial_sets[i][j]);
  }
}
console.log(sets);
```