# Javascript cannot set property 0 of undefined

Tags: javascript

This code generates error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

While I want to assign random numbers in array, please help.

```js
var array;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: You haven't assigned "array" to anything, it is not currently an array object

Comment: Define `array` as an array `var array=[];` and to avoid getting undefined for `array[0]` I would recommend you change your loop `var i = 0; i<9;i++` or maybe use `array.push();`

Comment: I follow your suggestion but still its not resolve.

Comment: @aashirkhan Maybe this will help. I have a working example of my suggestions. https://jsfiddle.net/zuzy01m2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673237/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-0-of-undefined)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing the array initialization:

```
var array = [];
```

Taking this into your example, you would have:

```js
var array = []; //<-- initialization here
for(var i = 1; i<10;i++) {
    array[i]= Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}
console.log(array);
```

Also you should starting assigning values from index `0`. As you can see in the log all unassigned values get `undefined`, which applies to your index `0`.

So a better solution would be to start at `0`, and adjust the end of `for` to `<9`, so that it creates the same number of elements:

```js
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i<9;i++) {
    array[i]= Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to add into your answer...... To avoid the array index **`0`** becoming **`undefined`**  replace `array[i]= Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);` with `array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7));` this will push items into the array rather than setting them via index.

Comment: var array;
for(var i =0; i<10;i++){
    array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7));
   
}
console.log(array);

Comment: @aashirkhan `var array` is the problem. You need to define it as an array. `var array=[]` Very important to have the variable **`array`** equal to **`[]`** In this example I have change the variable name from `array` to `Myarray` to save any misunderstanding https://jsfiddle.net/xuz4hgf3/

Comment: @aashirkhan Very welcome. You can also define the variable `array` like this too `var array=new Array();` Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lqduwy9/

Comment: @aashirkhan you should accept this answer and mark is accepted. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told that `array` is an array  Tell to javascript that treat that as an array,

```
var array = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize the array first

```
 var array = [];
```

after adding this line your code should work properly